# Map and route planning software for Mac

Tags: osx, maps, gps

I'm looking for the Mac equivalent of Ozi-Explorer.

- Can load and geo-reference map files, tiling multiple map files together.
- Can load, edit and save track data.
- Nice to have: Talks to my GPS (not required, I can find other programs to read/write to the GPS)
- is not locked into a proprietary map format.

It does NOT need to be able to convert map files to be usable on my GPS.

The idea is to make it reasonable to have a directory of map files, plan a trip, then figure out what paper maps I need to buy. Also to pre-load tracks into the GPS for use on the trip.

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill but take a look at [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) -

- Cross Platform
- Open Source
- Gratis (free)
- Can work with multiple sources and formats of information
- Modules available to interface with various GPSs

To quote the web site:

> GRASS GIS, commonly referred to as GRASS (Geographic Resources
>   Analysis Support System), is a free and open source Geographic
>   Information System (GIS) software suite used for geospatial data
>   management and analysis, image processing, graphics and **maps
>   production,** spatial modeling, and visualization. GRASS GIS is
>   currently used in academic and commercial settings around the world,
>   as well as by many governmental agencies and environmental consulting
>   companies. It is a founding member of the Open Source Geospatial
>   Foundation (OSGeo).

Comment: Interesting.  Good possible answer.  Take my point.